# Get Distinct name of elements with a class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

Radio button list(s):

```
<input name="rdLst163" class="required_Mandatory_RbtLst" id="rdLst163_1" onclick="fn("1631");" type="radio" value="1"/>
<input name="rdLst163" class="required_Mandatory_RbtLst" id="rdLst163_2" onclick="fn("1632");" type="radio" value="2"/>
<input name="rdLst163" class="required_Mandatory_RbtLst" id="rdLst163_3" onclick="fn("1633");" type="radio" value="3"/>

<input name="rdLst164" class="required_Mandatory_RbtLst" id="rdLst164_1" onclick="fn("1641");" type="radio" value="1"/>
<input name="rdLst164" class="required_Mandatory_RbtLst" id="rdLst164_2" onclick="fn("1642");" type="radio" value="2"/>
<input name="rdLst164" class="required_Mandatory_RbtLst" id="rdLst164_3" onclick="fn("1643");" type="radio" value="3"/>
```

Checkbox list(s):

```
<input name="chLst165" class="required_Mandatory_ChkLst" id="chkLst165_1" onclick="fn("25");" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<input name="chLst165" class="required_Mandatory_ChkLst" id="chkLst165_2" onclick="fn("25");" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
<input name="chLst165" class="required_Mandatory_ChkLst" id="chkLst165_3" onclick="fn("25");" type="checkbox" value="3"/>

<input name="chLst166" class="required_Mandatory_ChkLst" id="chkLst166_1" onclick="fn("25");" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<input name="chLst166" class="required_Mandatory_ChkLst" id="chkLst166_2" onclick="fn("25");" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
<input name="chLst166" class="required_Mandatory_ChkLst" id="chkLst166_3" onclick="fn("25");" type="checkbox" value="3"/>
```

and the following jQuery :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.required_Mandatory_ChkLst[name!=]'); 
  $('.required_Mandatory_RbtLst[name!=]');
// result is fetching all 6 elements. I need only distinct element names [here 2 elements] in each class.
});
</script>
```

how can I get distinct element names of class in jQuery?

Required result:

```
["rdLst163", "rdLst164"]  
["chLst165", "chLst166"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var cbnames = [];
$('.required_Mandatory_ChkLst[name!=]').map(function() {
    return this.name;
}).each(function(i, str) {
    if (!~$.inArray(str, cbnames)) cbnames.push(str);
});
console.log(cbnames); //["chLst165", "chLst166"]
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xpp7C/1)

Simply put, this solution [maps](http://api.jquery.com/map/) the elements' names into a jQuery object-wrapped array which is [iterated](http://api.jquery.com/each/) upon and the unique values are [pushed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) into an array.

---

Mapping is not quite necessary, so for simplicity you could also do it skipping that step.

```
var cbnames = [];
$('.required_Mandatory_ChkLst[name!=]').each(function() {
    if (!~$.inArray(this.name, cbnames)) cbnames.push(this.name);
});
console.log(cbnames); //["chLst165", "chLst166"]
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xpp7C/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/DvegQ/

**Code:**

```
var classNames = [];
$('*').each(function() { classNames[$(this).attr('name')] = 1; });
for(var x in classNames) { console.log(x); }
```

Comment: @techfoobar, what is 1 that you assign for classNames in function

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is this

```
var mapped = $('.required_Mandatory_ChkLst[name!=], .required_Mandatory_RbtLst[name!=]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('name');
});

var unique = mapped.filter(function (i, itm) {
    return i == $.makeArray(mapped).indexOf(itm);
});

console.log(unique);
```

First we map the collection of dom elements to that of string values with the name of said element.
Secondly we filter this collection of names to only contain unique instances.

**Note:** Other answers suggest the use of jQuery.unique. This method however works on collections of dom elements and in your case all of these are unique.

Comment: Thanks for the combined answer

Comment: @rohith86 if you like the different answers please choose to vote them up.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to `filter()`:

```
$(function(){
    var names = [];
    $('.required_Mandatory_RbtLst').each(function(){

        if($.inArray($(this).prop('name'), names) === -1)
            names.push($(this).prop('name'));
    });

    console.log($(names));
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `.unique()` method,

```
jQuery.unique($('.required_Mandatory_RbtLst[name!=]'));
```

REF: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

Comment: Have you tried it? The elements are different, name attributes are equal. IMO, `.unique` will return the same array.

Comment: @Never back Down: The selector is returning all 6 elements.. 
I tried
    jQuery.unique($('.required_Mandatory_RbtLst[name!=]'));

Comment: @rohith86 Have you tried my answer? `unique()` should take an array of dom elements as the argument, not a jquery object.

Comment: @Johan: That didn't work either, but the new method you suggested is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var names = $("input").map(function(){ return $(this).attr('name'); });
var distinctNames = $.unique(names);
```

read more about the map function here http://jqapi.com/#p=map